# Set selection color transparent and border color red in QGis using python

Tags: python, qgis

I have a layer with different information. Whenever I select any polygon I want to change the selection color to "Transparent". I am able to achieve that using

```
iface.mapCanvas().setSelectionColor( QColor("Transparent") )
```

But i want the border color different (Red or any other color). As an example, in ArcMap there is an option to set the border color, border width and many more.

How i can achieve the same using Python script in QGIS?

Comment: You might have better luck on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ for questions on how to use GIS.

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/174664/115